# Download web content and load on Android webview at runtime

Tags: android, webview, internal-storage

I want to load a **local** web content on a webview. I'm downloading a zip file, unzipping it and saving the files (main.html and resource files - css, js, fonts, pngs, etc) on internal storage (`/data/data/<app>/files/`).

All files are in the same directory:

|- main.html
|- file.js
|- ...

So, the html file points resource files as follows:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`

I though this would work

```
String path = context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "main.html";
webview.loadUrl("file://" + path)
```

but the webview shows `file not found` error in pre lollipop devices, and in lollipop devices shows:

"The webpage at `file:///data/data/<app>/files/main.html` could not be loaded because: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED"

If I load the html as a string by running

```
String file = htmlFile.fileToString();
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", file, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

it works, but I have to resolve the dependencies by providing the full path of all resource files. There must be a better way to deal with this.

Does anyone know how to load a local file on a webview that was stored at runtime in Android?

Thanks

Comment: show me your manifest file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I forgot the config methods of the webview.

`webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false)`

This was the problem. By turning to `true` the webview is able to load local files.